# Trouble with USB drive and GRUB loader with ParrotOS

Tags: linux, usb, grub, bootloader

I have an older MacbookPro i believe an 08 model. I have installed ParrotOS Security on metal. I have now wanted to swap back to Kali but when I put the USB in it to install Kali, the grub bootloader does not show Kali drive or my USB thumb drive. I have tried to use BalenaEtcher and also Rufus and neither will show in the grub loader. Can someone help me find a way for Grub to load the thumb drive so i can select at boot? Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Rufus, Etcher and similar tools have problems to detect a drive correctly and prevent rewrites when for example the option to make use of `dd` instead of the iso-approach was utilized. This happens when either the `.iso` is not hybrid, when using an `.img`, `.raw`, `.usb` or similar or when manually selecting to use `dd` mode - or in fact use `dd` directly from the commandline.

Reason for this is that a specific block-size was requested which is not conform to the hardware underlying (the USB-drives adapter/flash-translator).

You can reset the drive by using `gdisk` ([GPTfdisk](http://rodsbooks.com/gdisk/)).

You can run it as an application from inside your OS (Linux/Windows/FreeBSD) or if your machine boots via UEFI by adding the EFI-version of GPTfdisk to your EFI-System-Partition and select it manually when you boot your computer.

Exemplary approach for a Debian/Ubuntu-based Linux-distribution:

1. In terminal enter

```
gdisk
```

... if the application is not found:

2.

```
sudo apt udpate
sudo apt install gdisk
```

3. After it installed, start gdisk pointing it to your device:

```
gdisk /dev/disk/by-id/usb-xyz123
```

... for example. Use the tab-completion after ..`/by-id/` to show the available recognized drives. You may want to ensure the selection by for example using Gnome Disks or a comparable tool that lists drives with their labels.

4. Since `gdisk` is now started operating on the drive you pointed it towards, it might happen that it asks you to choose how the drive shall be interpreted due to a mbr/hybrid-mbr or a corrupted table being found. If that is the case select to treat it as GPT. This does not affect nor is it dependent on how you want to reuse your drive later on - this is meant to make sure the drive gets a fresh and complete descriptor. Now enter:

```
o
```

... (the letter o) - this will overwrite the existing configuration with a clean blank gpt structure.

5. Windows (since you mentioned `rufus`) sometimes does make problems recognizing completely wiped drives that have a correct descriptor. To prevent it from misinterpretation add a partition:

```
n
```

... this will start the dialogue to create a new partition. Just accept the default values by pressing enter.

6. Now check the result by pressing:

```
p
```

... this command will print the partition table as you so far defined it. Check if everything is correct.

7. Now enter:

```
w
```

... to write the freshly created partition-table and drive-descriptor to the drive.

The program will bring you back to the shell after that is done.

8. To ensure the kernel is informed about the changes to the partition table use:

```
sudo partprobe
```

After that the drive should already be visible in your disk-management tool of choice.

If that is not the case or if other problems do arise, please make sure to add specifics of the hardware and software in use, meaning Which version of distro/windows, which desktop-environment, etc. as a distro comes in different flavours and versions do matter too.

Comment: Thank you for the very descriptive help and walk through! After completing all of the steps you mentioned the thumb drive went from the file system name KALI LINUX to a regular named drive and kept all the files. Upon rebooting the machine and bringing Grub up, I still cannot see the drive in the list to select to boot from. It shows while I am logged into the machine and I can open to view the files but it still does not show in GRUB for some reason. I have also tried different Distros flashed to the USB and none of them are able to be seen upon loading into Grub.